# Unity3d new UI: How to set button's interactable zone bigger than the attached image?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need it because the `image` is small and it's difficult to touch it on the mobile device. So I need to have bigger area of interactable zone but the `image` should stay small.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the most proper way to make such button is like this:

1. Create a new Button, remove default child Text.
2. Set `Width` and `Height` of Button as you need for hitzone size.
3. Add `Vertical Layout Group` *component* to the Button.
4. Set `Padding` of the `Vertical Layout Group` to desirable difference between hitzone and visuals.
5. <s>Remove default `Image` *component*.</s> Set alpha of default `Image` component to zero.
6. Put your Image as child of Button.
7. Fix tint: drag (or otherwise set) the child `Image` to `Target Graphic` *field* of `Button`.

Comment: Thanks it works. But you should not remove default Image component (step 5), you should just set alpha to 0. When you remove the image component on button the hitzone would equal to size of child image (that is smaller).  Also you don't have to do 3rd step.

Answer (score 9):

You need to set it up so that the image is inside a button object. Like this:

[image]

This way you can have the *Button* as big as you want and the *Image* can be any size. If you don't need the *Button* background image just make the color transparent in the image componenent of the *Button* object.

Comment: Yes, but the image doesn't tint when you press button. Are there any ready solutions or should I tint manually?

Comment: When you add a new `Image` as a child of `Button`, you also need to change the **Target Graphic** of the **Button (Script)** to reference that new image.

Comment: This is my goto method, but I always wonder about transparency performance

Answer (score 9):

A surprisingly better way (in terms of ease and performance) is to add a text child element, even if you already have one. Leave the text empty and resize it however you like. It doesn't add any alpha.

Comment: This was a really good solution, I did not have to change my current button either.

Comment: It's a hack but it works wonderfully, a real saver when you don't want to start tweaking your layouts, you can just enlarge the touch area with the invisible text box.

Answer (score 4):

Unity now have `Raycast Padding` property on Image component, edit these padding values will allow you to have more interactable zone for your button image. Note that you use negative value to extend the click zone.

[image]